# Attracting positive users to the community

Tags: promotion

In the age of the Eternal September, how can I avoid attracting immature users to my community, while still drawing a steady flow of new users?

What is the best way to ensure the community feels age-appropriate to the users that I want to target, while limiting the impact of younger members joining quickly and driving the quality of the content in my community down?

Comment: I don't see how this can be answered in a generic way. What kind of audience does your community target?

Comment: The best way to attract positive users to the community is to rub the community with a glass rod. Physics 101!